# IDE for Selenium + Protractor e2e testing

Tags: software-development, javascript, web-development, ide, node.js

I started writing some `Selenium` test with `Protractor` and ran into some debugging issue. I am a C# guy and using VS2013 for development. I did some research and found out [this](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/). I have little experience of using `WebStorm` and also used/using `Intellij` from JetBrains. Since `protractor` and `nodejs` both are fairly new to me I am not sure which `IDE` is best to start off with. I prefer something related to VS2013 since I am well versed on that but open to others as well. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebStorm` is definitely the best choice for angularjs/protractor development.

You would need to let `WebStorm` know which libraries you are using by configuring `libraries`, see:

- [Configuring JavaScript Libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html)

Here is what libraries I have installed during an active `protractor` e2e test development:

[image]

You would also need to have a separate run configuration for debugging your tests:

- [Setting Up WebStorm for Debugging](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#setting-up-webstorm-for-debugging)

There is also an extended version of `elementexplorer.js` available as a WebStorm plugin:

- [`elementor`: Using the Webstorm / IntelliJ plugin](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor#using-the-webstorm--intellij-plugin)

Comment: I appreciate it sir. Will definitely check this out after work. Setting protractor up is little bit tricky

Comment: alexce, do you have experience with protractor recorders for creating E2E scripts from user input? I've found a few open source and couple commercial tools, but can't find any reviews, comparisons, any articles outlining pros, cons, etc

Comment: @DaveAlperovich unfortunately, I don't recall and have not used any of such tools. I think I've only used "elementor" browser extension couple times, but it is of course far from being a recorder..which tools have you found? Thanks.